# problem with jdbc when I use Jar file and command prompt

Tags: java, oracle, command-line, jdbc

I use JDeveloper for develop a JDBC program, now my program finished and I want to run it separately I have problem when I try to run my jar file from command prompt.

my program cannot connect to my oracle database when I am using command prompt to run my program!But When I use my JDeveloper IDE there is no issue!
my IDE run this command:

```
javaw.exe -client -classpath C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\.adf;C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\classes;C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\jdev\lib\jdev-rt.jar;C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\ojdbc14.jar;C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\quaqua-filechooser-only.jar;C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\quaqua-test.jar;C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\quaqua.jar;C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\swing-layout.jar;C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\image;C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\lipstikLF-1.1.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks Main.GUI.SmRun amir
```

I use this command :

```
Java -jar smt.jar amir
```

when I run my IDE command there is no issue,every thing work fine, would you please help me? (my program running & working just I can not fetch data from database)

I receive below error when I try to select from my database...

```
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SourceManagmentTools\Client\deploy>java -jar smt.jar amir
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7a148bd3[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@51b48197[L
java.lang.StackTraceElement;@58ecb281[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@25fa1bb6[Lja
va.lang.StackTraceElement;@62da3a1e[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@15f48262[Ljava
.lang.StackTraceElement;@7dc05ffd[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@15e232b5[Ljava.l
ang.StackTraceElement;@36baa466[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@177f409c[Ljava.lan
g.StackTraceElement;@2b8bbc5a[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@62facf0b[Ljava.lang.
StackTraceElement;@5ff3ce5c[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@561777b1Exception in t
hread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Main.Database.SmDatabase.selectCustomers(SmDatabase.java:151)
        at Main.GUI.SmCreateProject.this_windowOpened(SmCreateProject.java:109)
        at Main.GUI.SmCreateProject.access$000(SmCreateProject.java:30)
        at Main.GUI.SmCreateProject$1.windowOpened(SmCreateProject.java:58)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowOpened(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JDialog.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

part of mydatabase class:

```
public class SmDatabase {

    Connection conn = null;

    public SmDatabase() {
        try {
            String drivername = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            Class.forName(drivername);

            String ServerName = "127.0.0.1";
            String ProtNumber = "1521";
            //String sid = "DEVP0";
            String sid = "cms";

            String url =
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + ServerName + ":" + ProtNumber + ":" +
                sid;

            //String Username = "PENTAVCB";
            //String Password = "pentasoft123";
            String Username = "cmsuser";
            String Password = "pass";

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, Username, Password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.print(se.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

public Vector<String[]> selectCustomers(String command) {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Statement statement;
    Vector<String[]> customerName = new Vector<String[]>();
    try {
        statement = conn.createStatement();
LINE151     resultSet = statement.executeQuery(command);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String[] temp = new String[2];
            temp[0] = resultSet.getString("V_CUST_NAME");
            temp[1] = resultSet.getString("V_CUST_CODE");
            customerName.add(temp);
        }
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        //    conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return customerName;
}
```

Comment: Confucius says: "He who cannot describe the problem will never find the solution to that problem"

Comment: what I mean is: "my program cannot connect to my oracle database!" is quite insufficient information

Comment: Sorry I am not native, sorry for my broken English...but if you want help me come on and press edit....

Comment: I already edit it & put more information

Comment: @Rima How about an error message? That's a good thing to show people when you ask for help.

Comment: you are not stating the problem again. Is it an exception? What is the exception?

Comment: @isaac : Take a look at my point, I have small knowledge to enplane my problem, but unfortunately this time there is no error message!everything working fine, my window will appearing exactly same as when I run my program with my IDE but the only problem is nothing fetch from database. I put e.printstackTrace() for all of my try & catch.... I dont know how I should track this issue :( help...

Comment: @rima then debug. add log messages. See if you are not swallowing exceptions. Show some code for example.

Comment: I add a exception... see what's your idea

Comment: What is on line 151 of SmDatabase

Comment: @rima Then the next step is to create the smallest code sample you can that demonstrates the problem in a way that others can reproduce. Don't just post your whole program - few people will want to dig through hundreds of lines of code looking for your problem. Start fresh and write a very small reproduction case. When you've reproduced the problem, ideally in a couple dozen lines of code, add  that to your question, and phrase your request for help in the form of a specific, objectively answerable question (since SO is a Q&A site). I'll be happy to answer the question if I can.

Comment: @isaac: I dont think there is any issue with code! it work in 2 computer with 2 different oracle server, what do you need I copy & paste for you? I guess there is some problem in my running form cmd! pleaseeeeeeeeeee check the way that JDeveloper run my program &  compare it with my way... the below solution also didnot worked.

Comment: @rima Code without issues doesn't throw uncaught exceptions. As @Bozho asked, what's on [and around] line 151 of SmDatabase?

Comment: I already paste part of my database class, look in java we need to add a package for jdbc and oracle, maybe it can not find those class??what's your idea about last parameter THAT my IDE use for run my program,can u explane me those parameter are for what?

Comment: Your exception handling is extremely poor. You're just printing it and continuing with the code flow. The code flow must be stopped when an exception occurs which you cannot handle. You need to **throw** the exception. Get rid of those silly printlns on the exception and add a `throws` clause to the method. JVM will print them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by using this command:

```
java -client -classpath ojdbc14.jar;lipstikLF-1.1.jar;swing-layout.jar;smt.jar Main.GUI.SmRun rimrim
```

I guess those library we used in our project need also run, but I am not sure, I just suggest this work

```
java -client -classpath <name of you library>;<name of you library>;<name of your jar file> nameOfPackage.nameOfRunClass parameter[if any]
```

I will so appreciate if anybody add some useful info to this post

Answer (score 0):

What exception are you getting? If it's a ClassNotFoundException, then you just need to add `-cp oracleclient.jar` to the command.

The Oracle client jar can also be put at the end of the `-classpath` arguement passed to `java.exe`.

Comment: skip my previous comment. where I should add it exactly? see my update note

Answer (score 0):

`e.printStackTrace();` will produce far more useful output than `System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());`. I would change that everywhere it appears in your application and try again. `DriverManager.getConnection(url, Username, Password);` is most likely throwing an exception that you're not printing properly, which produces the "[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement..." garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The output indicates a null pointer exception at line 151 which should indicate that the "statement" variable is null. The "conn" is not null or the exception would have been thrown at the previous line. This is strange, if you have a valid connection tyou should be able to get a Statement. Is it possible the line number is off by 1? Can you change your code to:

```
   if conn is null  System.out.println("conn is null!!!");
   else System.out.println("conn is set");

   statement = conn.createStatement();   

   if statement is null  System.out.println("statement is null!!!");
   else System.out.println("statement is set");

   resultSet = statement.executeQuery(command);

   if resultSet is null  System.out.println("resultSet is null!!!");
   else System.out.println("resultSet is set");
```

I don't see where SmDatabase is called to set conn. Is it called from somewhere else? Does the call catch the exception and not print an error message?

Comment: I suspect the line indicated is off by one, as that is the simplest explanation. Razors and all that.